# Evaluating OPF3 (ORM framework for .NET)

Tags: .net, orm, opf3

Is anyone using or has anyone evaluated [OPF3](http://opf3.com) as an ORM (.NET)? How does it stack up against EntitySpaces or Subsonic?

One thing about OPF3 I like in my evaluation so far is that it is very easy to customize. Since it binds database fields to object members using attributes, you do not *need* to use any code generation tool. This also means you can basically create your own classes, and then add OPF3 data binding on top of that.

```
<Persistent("users")> _
Public Class User

    <Field("userid", AutoNumber:=True, Identifier:=True, allowDbnull:=False)> _
    Public Property ID() As Long

    <Field("name", allowDbnull:=False)> _
    Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

They do have a generation tool, and one thing I don't like is that the demo will not output classes, so I can't actually see what it is *really* going to do.  On the plus side again, it appears that when you buy the tool, you get the source for it as well.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Opf3 at my company and until now it works great, except that it's having more functionality than needed. But watch out how u construct your classes, creating a new item to add as a child the ObjectSetHolder can be tricky. New items don't have any informatio about the ObjectContext unless u attach them to the ObjectContext using _context.Attach()

Anyway i personally like Opf3 and what it can do, but we don't use the wizzard since it doesn't really work against our database Pervasive.

Comment: Just going back and reading some older stuff, it's actually quite interesting you posted that: I just posted about a problem with child creation: http://opf3.com/Opf3/Community/Topic.aspx?Forum=2&Topic=1605.
I'll have to look at the .attach() method, thanks!